# How to get specific values with between range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database I'm trying to work on, but I have a little bit of a problem. The code is long and there are a lot of joins, so I will add it in the end. My problem is this. I get what I want when I use this line:

```
 FORMAT(sum(case quarter(ord2.OrderDate) when '1' then ord.UnitPrice*ord.Quantity else 0 end), 0) as "quarter1"
```

However, I want to use this line:

```
Format(sum(case when ord2.OrderDate between('%-01-01%') and ('%03-31%') then ord.UnitPrice*ord.Quantity end),0) as "quarter1"
```

However, in line 2 I get value in quarter 1 as null in all of the columns. Why  doesn't this line doesn't?

My code:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE myPrecuder (IN ProductNAME VARCHAR(30))
    BEGIN
        SELECT p.ProductName, cus.CompanyName, year(OrderDate) as year,
            FORMAT(sum(case quarter(ord2.OrderDate) when '1' then ord.UnitPrice*ord.Quantity else 0 end), 0) as "quarter1"
        from Products as p 
            Join `order details` ord on (p.ProductID = ord.ProductID)
            Join orders as ord2 on (ord2.OrderID = ord.OrderID)
            Join customers as cus on (cus.CustomerID = ord2.CustomerID) 
            WHERE p.ProductName = ProductNAME
        Group by p.ProductName, cus.CompanyName, year(OrderDate)
        ORDER by p.ProductName, cus.CompanyName;
    END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to treat dates as string  you can't use between.

so you gave to use sting methods to get your data

Like

> ```
> CREATE tABLE ord2(OrderDate Date,UnitPrice int, Quantity int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ord2 VALUES ('2021-01-01',1,1),('2021-04-01',2,1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     FORMAT(SUM(CASE
>             WHEN ord2.OrderDate LIKE '%-01-%'  THEN ord2.UnitPrice * ord2.Quantity
>             WHEN ord2.OrderDate LIKE ('%-03-%') THEN ord2.UnitPrice * ord2.Quantity
>             WHEN ord2.OrderDate LIKE ('%-03-%') THEN ord2.UnitPrice * ord2.Quantity
>         END),
>         0) AS 'quarter1'
>         
>  FROM ord2
> ```
>
> ```
> | quarter1 |
> | :------- |
> | 1        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=def0618ccd954d79a85332fba72aa4de)*

But keep QUARTER is looks much simpler

Comment: oh i get it, thanks, now i need to add each month manually. but now i understand why it didn't work !